# Visual Studio SharePoint solution overwrites machineKey

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, machinekey

Exactly what it says on the tin - any time I make a change in a SharePoint 2010 solution which results in web.config being updated by visual studio, it makes changes to the element

```
<machineKey validationKey="{key}" ...
```

Prevents login. Must be the key I specify.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the machine key being overwritten, make the following change:

Navigate to http:///Lists/HealthRules/AllItems.aspx

1. Find the item “Web.config files are not identical on all machines in the farm.” And click it
2. Click Edit Item > disable the Enabled & Repair Automatically
   checkboxes > click Save

(You can confirm its this setting by using the "Run Now" "Feature")